# To which em do 18mu correspond?

Tags: fonts, dimensions

I am a bit puzzled about the output of this code

```
\mathsurround=0pt

1)%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\mkern18mu$}
\number\wd0

2)%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\kern1em$}
\number\wd0

3)
\number\fontdimen6\textfont0

4)
\number\fontdimen6\textfont2

\bye
```

which returns

```
1) 655344
2) 655361
3) 655361
4) 655361
```

and apparently contradicts the statement `18mu=1em`. Now, IIRC `\kern` in a math formula might refer to the last *text* font so the difference between 1) and 2) could be explained. However, if this were the case then 2) and 3) should output the same number (unless I'm heavily misunderstanding something, which is quite likely).

Admittedly I won't be able to see the 90nm difference but I still like to know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
\newdimen\tmpdim

\tmpdim=655361sp
\number\tmpdim

\divide\tmpdim by18  \multiply\tmpdim by18
\number\tmpdim
\bye
```

The result is 655361 and 655344. You can see, that this is only rounding problem.

Comment: Oh, that was easy. So the internal quantity is `em`, and `mu` is just calculated by TeX integer arithmetic, right?

Comment: TeX stores all dimens in sp units. The `mu` must be represented in sp units and you want to see the multiply by 18 of this quantity: `\mkern18mu`, i.e. TeX integer arithmetic is done here.

Answer (score 6):

The `mu` unit is defined so that 18mu is the same as 1em in the current font for math family 2 (math symbols). Hence it uses the em for `\textfont2`, `\scriptfont2` or `\scriptscriptfont2`, depending on what math style the mkern or mskip eventually happens to be.

In the standard setting with Computer Modern, the em is the same in cmr10 and cmsy10, but this is not enforced and with other fonts the em size can be different.

A “big” difference is seen if `\scriptscriptstyle` is used, because the em for `\fiverm` is 6.80565pt, whereas for `\fivesy` (or `\scriptscriptfont2`) it is 7.3612pt.

With `\setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern18mu$}\showthe\wd0` you get 8.19443pt, but `\showthe\fontdimen6\scriptfont2` yields 8.19447pt because of small rounding errors.

The same in the other styles.